# My query is very Slow

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

With Symfony and Doctrine, I have a very simple query but very very slow

**530 résults on phpmyadmin, 0,0001 seconds :**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_a T1
    INNER JOIN
        table_b T2 ON
        T2.table_b.id = T1.id
WHERE
    T1.id = 1
```

**And I join third table :**

**245390 results (530 *(from table_b)* X 430 *(from table_c)*) on phpmyadmin, 4 seconds :**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_a T1
    INNER JOIN
        table_b T2 ON
        T2.table_b.id = T1.id
    INNER JOIN
        table_c T3 ON
        T3.table_a.id = T1.id
WHERE
    T1.id = 1
```

I have index A = B and A = C (With doctrine:schema:update)

I can do two queries but I do not understand the problem

Can you help me ?

Comment: What is the second `FROM` in both queries? Maybe `WHERE`?

Comment: The problem is that you return the complete record set (`select *`) on 250k record into your program.

Comment: Yes, it's Where ^^

Comment: @Gaylord.P why use * ?

Comment: But If I want all results (With Symfony / Doctrine, for hydratation objects) ?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

Four seconds to handle a result set with a quarter million rows in it **isn't slow**. It's actually pretty fast.

When doing JOIN operations, **SELECT * is harmful.** You end up with duplicate-valued columns. In a result set with a quarter million rows, that's a lot of wasted time and space, both in the MySQL server and in your client program. Instead of using SELECT *, give a list of the columns you need in the result set.  Enumerating the columns you need also helps the MySQL query planner optimize things. Usually, when a query really is slow, one of the first optimization steps is to cut down the number of columns.

Notice that joining two tables causes a **combinatorial explosion**. That's what JOIN means. You get back every possible pair of records matching the `ON` clause. As you know, this is what is causing you trouble -- 530 x 430 records.

You didn't describe your data. It sounds like the rows of your `table_b` and `table_c` are separately related to `table_a`, but not to each other. That probably means you should retrieve `table_a JOIN table_b` with one query, and `table_a JOIN table_c` with a second query.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not slow for me. But you can check use of resources with **show profile/-s** function. It shows you which part of your query is the slowest.

Needed documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profiles.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html